# android studio java App crashes after FirebaseAuth. auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); in SignUP Activity

Tags: java, firebase, authentication, crash

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nikespr/com.example.nikespr.SignupActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.nikespr. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.nikespr. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:184)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:1)
at com.example.nikespr.SignupActivity.onCreate(SignupActivity.java:28)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
2022-06-30 04:54:24.785 1639-2693/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
2022-06-30 04:54:24.785 1639-2693/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
2022-06-30 05:07:47.663 1639-1660/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2022-06-30 05:07:47.665 1639-1660/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
2022-06-30 05:07:47.884 1639-1660/system_process E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2022-06-30 05:07:47.885 1639-1660/system_process E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat (No such file or directory)
2022-06-30 05:07:47.886 1639-1660/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()`?

Comment: What is the code that produces that error? Please add it to your question.